# D3.js scale: Return the smaller of a constant and the value of a scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 ordinal scale that I'm using in a bar chart:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);
```

I call it like this to position a number of `g` elements, one for each bar in my bar chart:

```
var barEnter = bar.enter()
  .insert("g", ".axis")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + (y(d.State) + height) + ")";
  });
```

It works really well when there are many bars, as they are spread evenly.

[image]

However, it works but doesn't look so good when there are just a couple of bars:

[image]

Is there a way I can modify either the `y` function, or the `transform` attribute, to set `transform` more sensibly when there are just a few bars? I don't completely understand what the ordinal scale is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: How do you generate the actual bars, i.e. the `rect` elements?

Comment: They're within the `g` element - their positioning is all the same, just offset from their parent `g` element.

Comment: And how do you calculate the height? What I'm driving at that a common way to fix this would be to increase the height of the bars so that the whole space is covered.

Comment: Thanks - but I don't want to do that, I think two bars that are each half the height of the graph would look even more strange.

Comment: Why don't you simply adjust the range of the `y` domain then? I.e. some constant times number of bars. This way you would have all the bars together at the top (or bottom).

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, this is how I solved it.

I realised that the problem occurred when the y scale's domain only had a couple of elements in it. So I ended up padding the scale's domain, as follows:

```
if (ydomain.length < 12) {
  for (var i = ydomain.length; i < 12; i++) {
    ydomain.push('y_' + i);
  }
}
y.domain(ydomain);
```

I doubt this is the most elegant way of doing things, but it worked.